# How to set Json Value with JQ as the result of command piped to JQ

Tags: bash, scripting, jq

I have a function in a bash script which gets an ID number from the JSON output of a command. I want to set this value in another JSON file. How can I do this?

```
build_vpc(){

      aws ec2 create vpc --Foo "ipaddress" | jq .Vpc.VpcID
}
```

```
Output : "vpc-0f482198efba76163"
```

I want to take this value and set it in another JSON file.

Json file :

```
{
  "VPC":{
         "VPC_ID" : ""
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be something like:

```
jq --argjson vpcid "$(
    aws ec2 create vpc --Foo "ipaddress" | jq .Vpc.VpcID
  )" 'setpath(["VPC","VPC_ID"]; $vpcid)' file.json > newfile.json
```

The output of `jq .Vpc.VpcID` is interpreted as json and stored in the `$vpcid` variable of the other `jq` which sets the `.VPC.VPC_ID` (the object at path `["VPC","VPC_ID"]`) of `file.json` to it.

I assume above that your `file.json` would initially have other information in there which should be preserved, and that you just want to *update* it with that new information.

If the point is to create a new `file.json` that contains just:

```
{
  "VPC":{
         "VPC_ID" : "that-value"
  }
}
```

You'd just need to do:

```
aws ec2 create vpc --Foo "ipaddress" |
  jq '{"VPC":{"VPC_ID":.Vpc.VpcID}}' > newfile.json
```